# Edit RecordStore Manually

Tags: java-me, recordstore

Can I edit the stored values of a RecordStore manually? If so, which programs do I need, or JVM stores those data in a file without any encryption?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "manually"? - from outside the MIDlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file format for RMS stores is not standardised. Every phone manufacturer can implement it however they see fit. The implementation is not supposed to let anything read the data outside the MIDlet Suite, though.

In order to do this, you would need to find the data first, then decrypt and/or reverse-engineer it. Not only is it difficult, it can also be illegal, depending on where you live.

Depending on your target handset platform, you may be able to access the data from native code if the handset manufacturer trusts you.